# AnimatorSet dont change background color on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, animator

I`am use AnimatorSet class for animating changing background color of listView item:

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(activity,
                R.animator.animator_bkg);
        set.setTarget(childLinear);
        set.start();
```

R.animator.animator_bkg:

```
<objectAnimator
  android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
  android:duration="3000"
  android:valueFrom="@color/white"
  android:valueTo="@color/redTrans"
  android:repeatCount="-1"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

On Lollipop devices it`s work perfectly and smoothly, but pre-lollopop dont change backgroung color and instead of this it only flickers by confusing color. I try to use library nineoldandroids, but no success.

Comment: I'm used it, but I need smooth changing in loop. It cant do it

Comment: i dont see any references to ArgbEvaluator in your code, BTW calling `setBackgroundColor` by an `Animator` is not a good thing as a new `ColorDrawable` will be created each time

Comment: ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
                            childLinear,
                            "backgroundColor",
                            new ArgbEvaluator(),
                            activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                            activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.redTrans));